# Prove that if $0<a<\Pr(A)$ then there exists $B\subset A$ such that $\Pr(B)=a$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

> Suppose $\Pr$ is non-atomic that is $\Pr(A)$ implies the existence of $B$ with $B\subset A$ such that $0<\Pr(B)<\Pr(A) $ and $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\Pr(A)>0$.
>
> (a)show that for every $\epsilon>0$, we have $B\subset A$ such that $0<\Pr(B)<\epsilon$.
>
> (b)Prove that if $0<a<\Pr(A)$ then there exists $B\subset A$ such that $\Pr(B)=a$.

Here is a hint:
fix $\epsilon_n \to 0$ and define inductively numbers $x_n$ and sets $G\in \mathcal{F}$ with $H_0=\emptyset$, $H_n=\cup_{k<n} G_k$, $x_n=\sup\{\Pr(G): G\subset A\setminus H_n, \Pr(H_n\cup G)\leq a\}$ and $G_n\subset A\setminus H_n$
such that $\Pr(H_n\cup G_n)\leq a$ and $\Pr(G_n)\geq (1-\epsilon_n)x_n$. Let $B=\cup_{k} G_k$.

Comment: See the "sketch of proof" here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures

Comment: Can you give us some indication of what you've done on the problem? What difficulties have you had executing the hint, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to prove for the second question, for the first one is a special case of the second, since for each $\epsilon>0$, we certainly can find an $a>0$ small enough such that $0<a<\min\{\mu(A),\epsilon\}$.

Here is a proof for the second question.

Let $0<\alpha<\mu(E)$. We shall find recurrence two sequences of measurable sets $(A_{n})$ and $(B_{n})$ with the following properties:

> 1) $A_{0}\subseteq A_{1}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq A_{n}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq B_{n}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq B_{1}\subseteq B_{0}\subseteq E$.
>
> 2) If we put 
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{n}&=\sup\{\mu(A): A_{n-1}\subseteq A\subseteq B_{n-1}, \mu(A)\leq\alpha\}\\
> b_{n}&=\inf\{\mu(B): A_{n}\subseteq B\subseteq B_{n-1}, \mu(B)\geq\alpha\},
> \end{align*}
>   the sequence $(a_{n})$ is decreasing, the sequence $(b_{n})$ is increasing and we have 
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{n}\leq\alpha\leq b_{n},~~~~n=1,2,...
> \end{align*}
>
> 3) There exist two sequences $(\epsilon_{n}),(\eta_{n})$, $\epsilon_{n},\eta_{n}\downarrow 0$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{n}-\epsilon_{n}<\mu(A_{n})\leq a_{n},~~~~b_{n}\leq\mu(B_{n})<b_{n}+\eta_{n},~~~~n=1,2,...
> \end{align*}

Here comes the construction.

Let $(r_{n})$, $r_{n}\downarrow 0$. Put
\begin{align*}
a_{0}=\sup\{\mu(A): A\subseteq E, \mu(A)\leq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $0\leq a_{0}\leq\alpha$. Pick an $\epsilon_{0}>0$, there exists a measurable set $A_{0}$ with $A_{0}\subseteq E$ and 
\begin{align*}
a_{0}-\epsilon_{0}<\mu(A_{0})\leq a_{0}.
\end{align*}
Put 
\begin{align*}
b_{0}=\inf\{\mu(B): A_{0}\subseteq B\subseteq E, \mu(B)\geq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $\alpha\leq b_{0}\leq\mu(E)$. Pick an $\eta_{0}>0$ there exists a measurable set $B_{0}$ with $A_{0}\subseteq B_{0}\subseteq E$ and 
\begin{align*}
b_{0}\leq\mu(B_{0})<b_{0}+\eta_{0}.
\end{align*}
Put then 
\begin{align*}
a_{1}=\sup\{\mu(A): A_{0}\subseteq A\subseteq B_{0},\mu(A)\leq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $a_{0}-\epsilon_{0}<a_{1}\leq a_{0}$ and if we take $0<\epsilon_{1}\leq r_{1}$ such that $a_{0}-\epsilon_{0}<a_{1}-\epsilon_{1}$, there exists a measurable set $A_{1}$ with 
\begin{align*}
A_{0}\subseteq A_{1}\subseteq B_{0},~~~~a_{1}-\epsilon_{1}<\mu(A_{1})\leq a_{1}.
\end{align*}
Put
\begin{align*}
b_{1}=\inf\{\mu(B): A_{1}\subseteq B\subseteq B_{0},\mu(B)\geq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $b_{0}\leq b_{1}<b_{0}+\eta_{0}$ and if we take $0<\eta_{1}<r_{1}$ such that $b_{1}+\eta_{1}<b_{0}+\eta_{0}$, there exists a measurable set $B_{1}$ with 
\begin{align*}
A_{1}\subseteq B_{1}\subseteq B_{0},~~~~b_{1}\leq\mu(A_{1})<b_{1}+\eta_{1}.
\end{align*}

Now we are ready to define recursively for the rest of the sets and sequences. Suppose that we have found $A_{1},...,A_{n},B_{1},...,B_{n},\epsilon_{1},...,\epsilon_{n},\eta_{1},...,\eta_{n}$ verifying the preceding three conditions. Put
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}=\sup\{\mu(A): A_{n}\subseteq A\subseteq B_{n},\mu(A)\leq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $a_{n}-\epsilon_{n}<a_{n+1}\leq a_{n}$ and if we take $0<\epsilon_{n+1}<r_{n+1}$ such that the inequality $a_{n}-\epsilon_{n}<a_{n+1}-\epsilon_{n+1}$ holds, there exists a measurable set $A_{n+1}$ with
\begin{align*}
A_{n}\subseteq A_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n},~~~~a_{n+1}-\epsilon_{n+1}<\mu(A_{n+1})\leq a_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
Put
\begin{align*}
b_{n+1}=\inf\{\mu(B): A_{n+1}\subseteq B\subseteq B_{n},\mu(B)\geq\alpha\}.
\end{align*}
Then $b_{n}\leq b_{n+1}<b_{n}+\eta_{n}$ and if we take $0<\eta_{n+1}<r_{n+1}$ such that $b_{n+1}+\eta_{n+1}<b_{n}+\eta_{n}$, there exists a measurable set $B_{n+1}$ with 
\begin{align*}
A_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n+1}\subseteq B_{n},~~~~b_{n+1}\leq\mu(B_{n+1})<b_{n+1}+\eta_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon_{n}\leq r_{n}$ and $\eta_{n}\leq r_{n}$, it follows that $\epsilon_{n},\eta_{n}\rightarrow 0$. These two sequences are also easily to be seen as monotone.

On the other hand, the sequences $(a_{n}),(B_{n})$ are monotone, they have limit and have
\begin{align*}
0\leq a\leq\alpha\leq b\leq\mu(E)<\infty.
\end{align*}
The sets 
\begin{align*}
A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n},~~~~B=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}
\end{align*}
are measurable and we have
\begin{align*}
A_{n}\subseteq A\subseteq B\subseteq B_{n}\subseteq E.
\end{align*}
From the third condition, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\mu(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{n})=a\leq\alpha.
\end{align*}
Since $\mu(B_{n})<\infty$, we also deduce that 
\begin{align*}
\mu(B)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(B_{n})=b\geq\alpha.
\end{align*}

Let $C$ be a measurable set such that $C\subseteq B-A$. Then $A_{n}\subseteq A\subseteq A\cup C\subseteq B\subseteq B_{n}$ for every $n=1,2,...$ If $\mu(A\cup C)\leq\alpha$, from the second and third conditions we deduce that $a_{n}-\epsilon_{n}\leq\mu(A\cup C)\leq a_{n+1}$ for all such $n$, consequently, $\mu(A\cup C)=a$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\mu(C)=\mu(A\cup C)-\mu(A)=0.
\end{align*}

If $\mu(A\cup C)\geq\alpha$, from the second and third conditions again we deduce that $b_{n+1}\leq\mu(A\cup C)\leq b_{n}+\eta_{n}$ for every $n=1,2,...$, consequently $\mu(A\cup C)=b$, therefore $\mu(C)=\mu(A\cup C)-\mu(A)=b-a=\mu(B)-\mu(A)=\mu(B-A)$.

Since $E$ has no atom, we deduce that $\mu(B-A)=0$, consequently $a=\mu(A)=\mu(B)=b$, therefore $\alpha=a=b$, and finally
\begin{align*}
\mu(A)=\alpha.
\end{align*}

The above proof is presented in the book by N. Dinculeanu, *Vector Measures*.

The author uses the following definition, which is also equivalent to the one presented in the post.

> We say that a measurable set $E$ is an atom with respect to $\mu$ if $\mu(E)>0$ and if for every measurable set $A$ with $A\subseteq E$ we have either $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(A)=\mu(E)$. We say that $\mu$ is atomic if there exists at least one atom, and that $\mu$ is non-atomic if there exists no atom.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a proof that follows your hint (this is also the hint given by Billingsley for the same exercise in the text *Probability and Measure*).

Following hint, we shall show $P(B) = a$.  By construction, it is easy to verify that $G_1, G_2, \ldots$ are disjoint and $G_n \subset A - \cup_{k < n}G_k \subset A$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$.  In addition, for every $n$, $\sum_{k = 1}^n P(G_k) \leq a$.
Since $P(G_k), k \geq 1$ are nonnegative, this implies $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty P(G_k) \leq a$.  It thus follows by countable additivity that
$P(\cup_k G_k) = \sum_{k \geq 1} P(G_k) \leq a$.  In the following we show that the strict inequality cannot hold, whence $\cup_k G_k$ is the
desired set $B$.

If $P(\cup_k G_k) < a$, then $P(A - \cup_k G_k) = P(A) - P(\cup_k G_k) > a - P(\cup_k G_k) > 0$, therefore by part (a) (take $\epsilon = 
a - P(\cup_k G_k) > 0$) we can choose $C \subset A - \cup_k G_k$ such that $0 < P(C) < a - P(\cup_k G_k)$.  Since $P(C) > 0$, we can choose
an $n$ sufficiently large so that $P(C) > \epsilon_n x_n$. Since $G_n \cap (A - \cup_k G_k) = G_n \cap (A \cap \cap_k G_k^c) = \varnothing$ and
$G_n \cup C \subset A - \cup_{k < n}G_k$ ($G_n \subset A - \cup_{k < n}G_k$ is straightforward, while $C \subset A - \cup_{k < n}G_k$ follows from
$\cup_{k < n}G_k \subset \cup_k G_k$ whence $C \subset A - \cup_k G_k \subset A - \cup_{k < n} G_k$). In addition, by the hypothesis,
\begin{align}
 & P(\cup_{k < n}G_k \cup (G_n \cup C)) = P(\cup_{k < n}G_k) + P(G_n) + P(C) \\
=& P(\cup_{k \leq n}G_k) + P(C) \leq P(\cup_k G_k) + P(C) < a.
\end{align}
This shows that $G_n \cup C \in \mathcal{G}_n$, where (with this notation, $x_n = \sup_{G \in \mathcal{G}_n}P(G)$)
$$\mathcal{G}_n = \{G: G \subset A - H_n, P(H_n \cup G) \leq a\}.$$
Hence $P(G_n \cup C) \leq x_n$.  Together with $P(G_n) \geq (1 - \epsilon_n)x_n$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
 & P(\cup_{k < n}G_k) + x_n \\
\leq & P(\cup_{k < n}G_k) + P(G_n) + \epsilon_n x_n \\
<& P(\cup_{k < n}G_k) + P(G_n) + P(C) \\
=& P(\cup_{k < n}G_k) + P(G_n \cup C) \leq P(\cup_{k < n} G_k) + x_n.
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction.  Therefore $P(\cup_k G_k) = a$.  This completes the proof.

---

Part (a) can be proved as follows (since part (b) uses part (a), we must establish an independent proof).

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{2^n}P(A) < \epsilon$.  Since $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is nonatomic, there exists
$B_1 \subset A$ such that $0 < P(B_1) < P(A)$, then either $0 < P(B_1) \leq \frac{1}{2}P(A)$ or $0 < P(A - B_1) \leq \frac{1}{2}P(A)$.  Let $A_1 = B_1$ if $0 < P(B_1) < \frac{1}{2}P(A)$ or $A_1 = A - B_1$ if $0 < P(A - B_1) \leq \frac{1}{2}P(A)$, then there exists
$B_2 \subset A_1$ such that $0 < P(B_2) < P(A_1)$, which either $0 < P(B_2) \leq \frac{1}{2}P(A_1)$ or $0 < P(A_1 - B_2) \leq 
\frac{1}{2}P(A_1)$. Let $A_2 = B_2$ if $0 < P(B_2) \leq \frac{1}{2}P(A_1) \leq \frac{1}{2^2}P(A)$ or $A_2 = A_1 - B_2$ if $0 < P(A - B_2)
\leq \frac{1}{2}P(A_1) \leq \frac{1}{2^2}P(A)$.  Continue in this way, we can obtain a decreasing sequence of sets $A \supset A_1 \supset A_2 \supset
\cdots$ such that $0 < P(A_k) \leq  \frac{1}{2^k}P(A), k = 1, 2, \ldots$. Take $B = A_n$, then $B \subset A$, and $0 < P(B) \leq 
\frac{1}{2^n}P(A) < \epsilon$.