# Stone Weierstrass polynomic approximation

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that a function  $F\in (C([0,1]\times [0,1],\mathbb{R})$ can be uniformly approximately by functions of the form

$$p(x,y)=(a_0+a_1x^2+...+a_{n_{1}}x^{n_{1}})(b_0+b_1y^2+...+b_{n_2}y^{n_2})$$

I'm trying to use Stone-Weierstrass real case for this exercise. But i'm very stuck. Can someone help me?

**My attempt:**
By Stone Weierstrass i proved that P[0,1] are dense in C[0,1]. As cartesian product of dense set is dense then $P[0,1]\times P[0,1]$  is dense in $C[0,1] \times C[0,1]$.

This implies for each function $f\in F$ exists a polynomic function $p$ such that $||f-p||_\infty<\epsilon$

Let $p(x,y)=(a_0+a_1x^2+...+a_{n_{1}}x^{n_{1}})(b_0+b_1y^2+...+b_{n_2}y^{n_2})$,

Here i'm stuck

Comment: It is not true, you mean by linear combinations of such products of two polynomials, add some symmetrized versions of $F$ to make it continuous on $[-1,2]\times [-1,2]$, take the convolution with $n^2 e^{-\pi n^2(x^2+y^2)}$ to obtain an analytic function, approach it by its Taylor expansion.

Comment: @reuns That means $F$ can't be approximate by uniformly by  functions of type polynomial?

Comment: A general polynomial in $x,y$ is of the form $\sum_{n,m} c_{n,m}x^ny^m$ not $(\sum_n a_n x^n)(\sum_m b_m y^m)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453448/prove-that-f-can-be-uniformly-approximated-for-functions-of-the-form-display) you already know that $\displaystyle\sum\varphi_{i}\psi_{i}$ approximates $F$, so given $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, we choose polynomials $p_{i},q_{i}$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\|\varphi_{i}-p_{i}\|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{nM},~~~~\|\psi_{i}-q_{i}\|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{nM},
\end{align*}
where $M=1+\|\varphi_{1}\|+\cdots+\|\varphi_{n}\|+\|\psi_{1}\|+\cdots+\|\psi_{n}\|$, then 
\begin{align*}
\|\varphi_{i}\psi_{i}-p_{i}q_{i}\|&\leq\|\varphi_{i}-p_{i}\|\|\psi_{i}\|+\|p_{i}\|\|\psi_{i}-q_{i}\|\\
&<\dfrac{\epsilon\|\psi_{i}\|}{nM}+\dfrac{\epsilon(\|\varphi_{i}\|+1)}{nM}\\
&<\dfrac{2\epsilon}{n},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum\phi_{i}\psi_{i}-\sum p_{i}q_{i}\right\|\leq\sum\|\phi_{i}\psi_{i}-p_{i}q_{i}\|<2\epsilon,
\end{align*}
we are done.

If one already recognizes that $C([0,1]\times[0,1])\approx C[0,1]\widehat{\otimes}C[0,1]$, the projective tensor product of copies of $C[0,1]$, the assertion will become immediate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a doubt about your proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414100/prove-that-if-0apra-then-there-exists-b-subset-a-such-that-prb-a is this the correct link for your approximation? because i don't see why F can be approximated for that type of functions

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Oh, yes but i have a question about that. How can you use that in this context? Because $C[0,1]$ is not compact. And we need that for hypothesis for apply that result

Comment: It is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, not the whole thing.

Comment: OHHHHHH, you have reason. Excellent! Thanks for all